# How to include SVG file in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, sass

I am making a small React based application and I am trying to include a magnifying glass icon SVG. However React keeps throwing an error and I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Error:

```
./src/Header.js
SyntaxError: /Users/klaurtar/Desktop/React JS/trillo-project/src/Header.js: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.
  13 |                     <button className="search__button">
  14 |                         <svg className="search__icon">
> 15 |                             <use xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#icon-magnifying-glass"></use>
     |                                  ^
  16 |                         </svg>
  17 |                     </button>
  18 |                 </form>
```

Here is my Header Component throwing the error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './img/logo.png';
import './Header.scss';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header className="header">
                <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>

                <form action="#" className="search">
                    <input type="text" class="search__input" placeholder="Search Hotels"/>
                    <button className="search__button">
                        <svg className="search__icon">
                            <use xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#icon-magnifying-glass"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form> 
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: best way to handle this is to create a separete .svg file and import it as component like: `import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from 'pathToMySvg'` and use it as regular component `<MySvg />`

Answer (score 6):

change xlink:href to xlinkHref because react uses camelCase